# How to animate small fire flames

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, effects, fire

I am just starting with blender. So, sorry if my question seems dumb.

I saw some videos on quick animations and I am amazed with it.

However, fire animation seems not to work when I scale the domain down to factor like 0.001. Why is it so? I am missing anything?

Thank you!

** **EDIT: added MWE .blend file.** **

[image]

Comment: *Short answer:* Simulations (no matter what kind) and how they are being calculated are an approximation of real world physics so always make sure the *scale is applied*.

Comment: Yes.. I applied the scale. Suppose I want to simulate the flame on the head of a match. I add an icosahedral sphere (standard 2 m in diameter), than scale it down by a factor of 0.001 (so that it gets 2 mm in diameter). Apply. Add the quick effect. Scale it down. Apply. But I see no flame as I run the animation. =/

Comment: Please add that to your question and ideally a blend using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. In general, the smaller your sim is, the more resolution is required, meaning smaller voxels.

Comment: Just added. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, @brockmann, any clue?

Comment: I guess the noise values are too high, I'd suggest try to disable the noise or lower all values. Otherwise what I've mentioned: *apply scale, voxel size (divisions) to at least 1024 and a good value for the temperature*... seems to work using your match head: https://i.stack.imgur.com/36bvS.png Unfortunately I don't have the time to write up a proper answer at the moment...

Comment: Same issue here for future reference (unsolved): https://blenderartists.org/t/small-scale-smoke-simulation/1408978